# .htaccess modifying url to remove index.html part

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a url like so: `www.blah.com/test/index.html` and I would like to change it to `www.blah.com/test/`. Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

However, when I try to go to `www.blah.com/test/` it gives me a 403:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test/ on this server.
```

Basically, `test` is a folder which contains the `index.html` file. Am I still able to do this?

Comment: If you directly visit `www.blah.com/test/`, doest it work?

Comment: No it gives me 403

Comment: Create a `test/.htaccess` and put this line there `Options +FollowSymLinks` followed by `DirectoryIndex index.html` line.